# Android java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Okay so I am storing a long in my shared preferences using

```
e.putLong("startTime", SystemClock.uptimeMillis());
```

and I am getting it from share preferences like

```
SHARED_PREFS = context.getSharedPreferences(LOCAL_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
long startTime = SHARED_PREFS.getLong("startTime", 0L); <-- Stack trace points to this line.
```

but I am getting this error on some devices and not sure why, I am not trying to cast it to a `String` at all.

```
java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Everything I find points towards trying to set this as a `String` value and I am not trying to do that at all, I am trying to use the `long` value directly.

** UPDATE STACK TRACE **

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:255)
        at com.tech.utility.Tools.refreshPrefs(Tools.java:193)
        at com.tech.activity.Menu_dashboard.onStart(Menu_dashboard.java:762)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1340)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7191)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2920)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate I updated with my stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to [read the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)) you would read that the `getLong` method will:

> Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not a long.

So, somewhere else in the app, you must have called:

```
e.putLong("startTime", "someString");
```

Comment: ha.. beat me to it by 10 seconds ;)

Comment: I only set it once in the entire app and that is when I create the timer, after that it is only used with `getLong`

Comment: @MarkKeen `at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:255)` is not one of my files and the line before that is `startTime = SHARED_PREFS.getLong("startTime", 0L);` , so I am not sure why it would try to access it as a `String`

Comment: Prehaps you set something in a previos version of the app, and the setting is still there? Can you try: A. Use a different variable name. B. Uninstall the app or clear all app data, then try again.

Comment: @user2101081 - not its AOSP code, which is resolved/called at runtime, its not part of the public SDK, that has the SharedPreferences API which calls this code. see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java - SharedPreferencesImpl holds a `Map<String, Object>` which is just cast based on requested type. Just clear data/cache in your app in settings and try again

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but for those who are still facing this problem, just overwrite this value in SharedPreferences with the value in the type you need before calling the get method. Perhaps a String (or other type) was written there before